# Can someone explain WPF Memory leak with FileStream?

Tags: wpf, memory-leaks

I'm opening a series of large files in a loop, and I'm getting a memory leak that I don't understand. 
The following code does not create a memory leak:

```
 DataContractSerializer dataContractSerializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(List<GeographicalEntity>), GetKnownTypes());
 List<GeographicalEntity> temporaryEntities;
 using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(dataFilePath, FileMode.Open))
 {
     temporaryEntities = dataContractSerializer.ReadObject(fileStream) as List<GeographicalEntity>;
 }
 geographicalEntities.AddRange(temporaryEntities);
 temporaryEntities.Clear();
 temporaryEntities = null;
 dataContractSerializer = null;
```

In contrast, the memory usage of the following code continues to increase:

```
 DataContractSerializer dataContractSerializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(List<GeographicalEntity>), GetKnownTypes());
 List<GeographicalEntity> temporaryEntities;
 using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(dataFilePath, FileMode.Open))
 {
      temporaryEntities = dataContractSerializer.ReadObject(fileStream) as List<GeographicalEntity>;
 }
 geographicalEntities.AddRange(temporaryEntities);
 //temporaryEntities.Clear();
 //temporaryEntities = null;
 dataContractSerializer = null;
```

I don't understand why the 'temporaryEntities' needs to be cleared and nullified. There are no other references to this variable. Can someone explain this behavior?

Comment: Implement dispose pattern in your GeographicalEntity which explicitly close/dispose the file handle when you are done.

Comment: @s_nair it doesn't look like the `GeographicalEntity` ever has a file handle - they are just being loaded from a file

Comment: It's WPF because it's a WPF assembly. Eventually the GeographicalEntities are loaded onto a Canvas, and rendered with RenderTargetBitmaps, but this is not the issue as the leak occurs without the drawing code.

Comment: @s_nair The GeographicalEntities are simple objects. They may as well be declared as "[DataContract]public class GeographicalEntity {}"

Comment: So many questions. What figure are you quoting when you say 13MB? Are you running a release build without a debugger attached? You say "series of large files", so is this code running in a loop? Your second example has an extra line of code at the start - is that intentional or did you miss that by accident? It's difficult to say without more information, and preferably a self-contained repro that we can all run.

Comment: 13Mb is the memory footprint of the running application. The code is running in a loop. I missed that line and will edit. I will try for a repro when I get a moment.

Comment: Well, your app may be a WPF app, but the problem has nothing to do with it, so you shouldn't mention it in the title and tags...

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the difference isn't rather in using temporaryEntities.Clear() or not? Because it is also commented out.

When a collection contains an object, this object won't be flagged for the garbage collection (it's also a reference).

Answer (score -1):

geographicalEntities.AddRange() appears to be collecting lists of GeographicalEntity's.

Why wouldn't memory usage go up?

The reason the first one doesn't is because you are adding them and then clearing them again, so geographicalEntities has a collection of empty lists.

EDIT: Actually just realised that geographicalEntities is a List<> too, so my last sentence doesn't apply.

I would guess that the quoted code is not representative of the real thing. The whole file read is nonsensical in the quoted code, so I would guess something has been lost in simplification.